# Count and select values of of a JArray with json.net

Tags: c#, linq, json.net

I have got a json array generated in c# from:

```
 var jArray = JArray.Parse(json);
```

which looks as follows:

```
 {[
 {
  "tbxSocialContents_3": "test"
 },
 {
  "txtSocialContentsImage_3": "C:\\fakepath\\photo.jpg"
 },
 {
 "txtSocialContentsImageValue_3": "photo.jpg"
 }
 ]}
```

I need to know how many elements of the array have a property which contains the text `txtSocialContentsImage` and if the `result is > 1` select the value of the property `txtSocialContentsImageValue_3`.

How can i do this in the c#?

Comment: This variable doesn't include from the above `txtSocialContentsImage`. Where do you want to do this? In HTML itself or In your code behind? provide  a better expected result.

Comment: Sorry, i edited the question. I need it in c#. I am not looking for the value, i am looking for the property names. In the example there are two properties names with the string txtSocialContentsImage which are : txtSocialContentsImage_3 and txtSocialContentsImageValue_3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Weird way to send a dictionary as an array of key-value pairs, but hey, who am i to judge.

Firstly, the JSON you posted is not an array, and you would get a `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Error reading JArray from JsonReader. Current JsonReader item is not an array: StartObject` exception trying to read that raw JSON. So we would assume you do actually have a correct JSON and remove leading and trailing squiggles.

This should work:

```
        var jArray = JArray.Parse(json);

        var matchedElements = jArray.Cast<JObject>().ToDictionary(item => item.Properties().FirstOrDefault().Name, item => item.Properties().FirstOrDefault().Value.Value<string>());

        if (matchedElements.Where(kv => kv.Key.Contains("txtSocialContentsImage")).Count() > 1 
            && matchedElements.Any(x => x.Key == "txtSocialContentsImageValue_3"))
        {
            return matchedElements["txtSocialContentsImageValue_3"];
        }
```

Comment: Thanks @MikeMat, after playing with the code for a bit i lost that important part..

Comment: Thanks @zaitsman. Your current answer produces the expected result. By the way "the array of key value pairs " is a string generated in the client that meets a specific logic.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use LINQ to accomplish this:

```
string json =  @"[{""tbxSocialContents_3"": ""test""},{""txtSocialContentsImage_3"": ""C:\\fakepath\\photo.jpg""},{""txtSocialContentsImageValue_3"": ""photo.jpg"",""txtSocialContentsImageValue_4"": ""photo2.jpg""}]";
        JArray arr = JArray.Parse(json);
        var testVal = from a in arr
            let sum = a.Children<JProperty>().Count(x => x.Name.Contains("txtSocialContentsImage"))
            let names = a.Children<JProperty>().Where(x => x.Name.Contains("txtSocialContentsImage"))
                .Select(x => x.Name)
            select new {Count = sum, Names = sum > 1 ? names : null};
```

It returns:

> [0]: { Count = 0, Names = null }
>   [1]: {Count = 1, Names = null }
>   [2]: {Count = 2, Names = {[0]: "txtSocialContentsImageValue_3", [1]: "txtSocialContentsImageValue_4"}}

Now you can sum all the values to get the total count or just keep them as it is.

Comment: Thanks @Yatin. The answer could be useful, however  I am not getting the specific result I was expecting.